# Averaging total word count after splitting in hiveql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have some data that contains info about journals and the papers published in them. I am trying to get the average length of the abstracts within each journal. The abstract column contains the whole abstract associated with the paper in that journal, so I want to split on space and get the word count for each and then group by the journal to average. So far I've tried:

This is the closest that I've gotten, but the resulting table is clearly not showing the total count of all the words in the abstract which is what I believe should be the result of this. I've also tried:

but this gives an error about having an aggregate within an aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `size` to get the number of words in each abstract:

```
select journal, avg(size(split(abstract, " ")))
from metadata_2020_05_01 where journal is not NULL 
group by journal sort by avg(size(split(abstract, " "))) desc limit 5
```

Comment: that worked, I will accept the answer when the time limit allows me. Can I ask what exactly is the difference between size, count, and sum? What was the original with count actually doing?

Comment: `count` is an aggregation function which counts the number of non-null items in a group. So what you got was simply the count of the number of abstracts, not the number of words. You're counting the number of arrays of words.

Comment: `size` gets the length of the array of words. It is not an aggregation function.